# GDB Write to History File In Eclipse / E2 Studio

Tags: eclipse, gdb

My team and I are working on an Embedded application that runs on an Eclipse based IDE, E2 Studio. I am looking to write an automated test suite which runs on the target hardware using the GDB debugger, however we are having some issues getting the app to run on the target using GDB outside of the IDE. I had the thought that we could tell GDB to log the history of commands into a logfile to get a better sense for what commands E2 Studio was sending to GDB. However, after configuring GBD to write the history log using the gdbinit file, the history file isn't getting generated upon exit of the app.

From within E2 Studio I can run the Show History command to see that the file is setup correctly.

```
show history
expansion:  History expansion on command input is on.
filename:  The filename in which to record the command history is "C:\Users\dm\Desktop\log\gdb.history".
save:  Saving of the history record on exit is on.
size:  The size of the command history is unlimited.
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the location of the output file either as I can manually run the GDB debugger using the same gdbinit file and it writes the log file on exit as expected.

My suspicion is that E2 Studio is terminating GBD in an expected way which is preventing the file from being written on exit. Is there a way in GDB to write the file before exit or has anyone gotten history files to work with Eclipse?